# SQL query error Vb.net Sqlite

Tags: sql, .net, vb.net, sqlite, syntax

I have this query:

```
    SQLcommand.CommandText = "UPDATE Pupil 
                SET Pupil_Name = '" & PDV_First_Name.Text & "' ,
                    Pupil_Middle_Name = '" & PDV_Middle_Name.Text & "' , 
                    Pupil_Surname = '" & PDV_Surname.Text & "' , 
                    Pupil_Prefferend_Name = '" & PDV_P_Name.Text & "' , 
                    Gender = '" & gender & "' , 
                    DOB = '" & Microsoft.VisualBasic.Left(PDV_bday.Value,10) & "' ,
                    Home_Languages = '" & PDV_Languages.Text & "' ,
                    Family_Religion = '" & PDV_Religion.Text & "' ,
                    Ethnicity = '" & PDV_Ethnicity.Text & "' ,
                    Form_ID = '" & Microsoft.VisualBasic.Trim(Microsoft.VisualBasic.Left(PDV_Form.Text,3)) & "' ,
                    Address_Line_1 = '" & PDV_Address_1.Text & "' ,
                    Address_Line_2 = '" & PDV_Address_2.Text & "' ,
                    Address_Line_3 = '" & PDV_Address_3.Text & "' ,
                    Postcode = '" & PDV_Postcode.Text & "' ,
                    Home_Tel = '" & PDV_Home_Tel.Text & "' ,
                    Parent_1_First_Name = '" & PDV_P1_First_Name.Text & "' ,
                    Parent_1_Surname = '" & PDV_P1_Surname.Text & "' , 
                    Parent_1_Relationship = '" & PDV_P1_CB_Relationship.Text & "' ,
                    Parent_1_Occupation = '" & PDV_P1_Occupation.Text & "' , 
                    Parent_1_Mobile_No = '" & PDV_P1_Mobile_No.Text & "' , 
                    Parent_1_Work_Number = '" & PDV_P1_Work_No.Text & "' , 
                    Parent_1_Email = '" & PDV_P1_Email.Text & "' ,
                    Parental_1_Responsibility = '" & parental1 & "' , 
                    Parent_2_First_Name = '" & PDV_P2_First_Name.Text & "' , 
                    Parent_2_Surname = '" & PDV_P2_Surname.Text & "' , 
                    Parent_2_Relationship = '" & PDV_P2_CB_Relationship.Text & "' ,
                    Parent_2_Occupation = '" & PDV_P2_Occupation.Text & "' , 
                    Parent_2_Mobile_No = '" & PDV_P2_Mobile_No.Text & "' , 
                    Parent_2_Work_Number = '" & PDV_P2_Work_No.Text & "' , 
                    Parent_2_Address_1 = '" & PDV_P2_Address_1.Text & "' , 
                    Parent_2_Address_2 = '" & PDV_P2_Address_2.Text & "' , 
                    Parent_2_Address_3 = '" & PDV_P2_Address_3.Text & "' , 
                    Parent_2_Postcode = '" & PDV_P2_Postcode.Text & "' , 
                    Parent_2_Home_No = '" & PDV_P2_Home_Number.Text & "' , 
                    Parental_2_Responsibility = '" & parental2 & "' , 
                    Family_Mem_1_First_Name = '" & PDV_FM1_First_Name.Text & "' , 
                    Family_Mem_1_Surname = '" & PDV_FM1_Surname.Text & "' , 
                    Family_Mem_1_Relationship = '" & PDV_FM1_Relationship.Text & "' , 
                    Family_Mem_2_First_Name = '" & PDV_FM2_First_Name.Text & "' , 
                    Family_Mem_2_Surname = '" & PDV_FM2_Surname.Text & "' , 
                    Family_Mem_2_Relationship = '" & PDV_FM2_Relationship.Text & "' , 
                    Collector_1_First_Name = '" & PDV_C1_First_Name.Text & "' , 
                    Collector_1_Surname = '" &  PDV_C1_Surname.Text & "' , 
                    Collector_1_Relationship = '" & PDV_C1_Relationship.Text & "' , 
                    Collector_1_Address_1 = '" & PDV_C1_Address_1.Text & "' , 
                    Collector_1_Address_2 = '" & PDV_C1_Address_2.Text & "' , 
                    Collector_1_Address_3 = '" & PDV_C1_Address_3.Text & "' , 
                    Collector_1_Postcode = '" & PDV_C1_Postcode.Text & "' , 
                    Collector_1_Tel_No = '" & PDV_C1_Work_No.Text & "' , 
                    Collector_1_Mob_No = '" & PDV_C1_Mobile_No.Text & "' , 
                    Collector_2_First_Name = '" & PDV_C2_First_Name.Text & "' , 
                    Collector_2_Surname = '" &  PDV_C2_Surname.Text & "' , 
                    Collector_2_Relationship = '" & PDV_C2_Relationship.Text & "' , 
                    Collector_2_Address_1 = '" & PDV_C2_Address_1.Text & "' , 
                    Collector_2_Address_2 = '" & PDV_C2_Address_2.Text & "' , 
                    Collector_2_Address_3 = '" & PDV_C2_Address_3.Text & "' , 
                    Collector_2_Postcode = '" & PDV_C2_Postcode.Text & "' , 
                    Collector_2_Tel_No = '" & PDV_C2_Work_No.Text & "' , 
                    Collector_2_Mob_No = '" & PDV_C2_Mobile_No.Text & "' , 
                    Collection_Instructions = '" & PDV_Collection_Instructions.Text &"' ,
                    Doctor_Name = '" & PDV_M_First_Name.Text & "' ,
                    Practice_Name = '" & PDV_M_Practice.Text & "' , 
                    Doctor_Address_1 = '" & PDV_M_Address_1.Text & "' , 
                    Doctor_Address_2 = '" & PDV_M_Address_2.Text & "' 
                    ,Doctor_Address_3 = '" & PDV_M_Address_3.Text & "' , 
                    Doctor_Postcode = '" & PDV_M_Postcode.Text & "' , 
                    Doctor_Contact_No = '" & PDV_M_Contact_No.Text & "' , 
                    Vaccinations = '" & PDV_M_Vaccinations.Text & "' , 
                    Allergies = '" & PDV_M_Allergies.Text & "' , 
                    Food_Dislikes '" & PDV_M_Dislikes.Text & "' , 
                    Special_Needs = '" & sn & "' , 
                    Special_Needs_Details = '" & PDV_M_Special_Needs.Text & "' ,
                    Medication_Application = '" & MA & "' , 
                    Medication_Details = '" & PDV_M_Medication.Text & "' ,
                    Medical_Problems = '" & PDV_M_Medical_Info.Text & "' ,
                    ICE_First_Name = '" & PDV_ICE_First_Name.Text & "' , 
                    ICE_Surname = '" & PDV_ICE_Surname.Text & "' , 
                    ICE_Relationship = '" & PDV_ICE_CB_Relationship.Text & "' , 
                    ICE_Address_1 = '" & PDV_ICE_Address_1.Text & "' , 
                    ICE_Address_2 = '" & PDV_ICE_Address_2.Text & "' , 
                    ICE_Address_3 = '" & PDV_ICE_Address_3.Text & "' , 
                    ICE_Postcode = '" & PDV_ICE_Postcode.Text & "' , 
                    ICE_Tel_No = '" & PDV_ICE_Home_No.Text & "' , 
                    ICE_Mob_No = '" & PDV_ICE_Mobile_No.Text & "' ,
                    Emergency = '" & A & "' , 
                    Safety = '" & B & "' , 
                    Information = '" & C & "' , 
                    Medical_Form = '" & D & "' ,
                    Stats = '" & U & "' , 
                    Consent_PG = '" & F & "' , 
                    Consent_Photo = '" & G & "' , 
                    Consent_Face_Paint = '" & H & "' , 
                    Consent_Trips_Dore_Village = '" & I & "' ,
                    Consent_Trips_Dore_Recc = '" & J & "' , 
                    Consent_Scooter = '" & K & "' , 
                    Consent_Plaster = '" & L & "' , 
                    Consent_Sun_Cream = '" & M & "' , 
                    Attendance_Monday = '" & N & "' , 
                    Attendance_Tuesday = '" & O & "' , 
                    Attendance_Wednesday = '" & P & "' , 
                    Attendance_Thursday = '" & Q & "' , 
                    Attendance_Friday = '" & R & "' , 
                    Signed = '" & S & "' , 
                    Sign_Date = '" & Microsoft.VisualBasic.Left(PDV_O_Datetime_Sign.Value,10) & "' , 
                    Waiting_List = '" & T & "' , Date_Of_Application = '" & Microsoft.VisualBasic.Left(PDV_O_Datetime_Application.Value,10) & "' , 
                    Date_Added = '" & Microsoft.VisualBasic.Left(PDV_O_Datetime_Added.Value,10) & "' , 
                    Added_By = '" & PDV_O_CB_Added.Text & "' , 
                    Other_Info = '" & PDV_Other.Text & "'  
                WHERE Pupil_ID = '" & Pupil & "'"
```

Which is pretty massive but everytime i run it i get a syntax error like this below:

```
System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException: SQLite error
near "''": syntax error
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.Prepare(SQLiteConnection cnn, String strSql, SQLiteStatement previous, UInt32 timeoutMS, String& strRemain)
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.BuildNextCommand()
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.GetStatement(Int32 index)
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader.NextResult()
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader..ctor(SQLiteCommand cmd, CommandBehavior behave)
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at ContactsDatabase.Search_Pupil.Button2Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in F:\Backup\ContactsDatabase\Search_Pupil.vb:line 1067
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(Int32 dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(ApplicationContext context)
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.OnRun()
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.DoApplicationModel()
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.Run(String[] commandLine)
   at ContactsDatabase.My.MyApplication.Main(String[] Args) in 17d14f5c-a337-4978-8281-53493378c1071.vb:line 81
```

I have checked manually and searched for this mysterious " '' " but it is not in this query! The only thing i can think of is that it is where a record is blank however in a very similar query i have for updating staff it doesn't error if it is blank! Please help!

Thanks

Comment: be sure your data that you  update the table with it,  does not contains single quote '  this may be cause such an error

Comment: Try to print the command text and see what it is generating before execution.

Comment: For the future, have a look at parameter queries and data binding. You're really doing this the hard way.

Comment: A separate issue from your exception, but this code is horribly vulnerable to sql injection attacks. It's practically begging to get hacked.

Comment: `I have ... searched forthis mysterious " '' " ` ... That sounds like you're looking for a double quote. The problem is not a double quote: it's two single quotes right together: an empty value somewhere you don't expect, or trying to assign text to a number or date time.

Comment: To demonstrate the security issue, try entering this for your first name (or don't, if you value your Pupil table): `';DROP Table Pupil;--`

Comment: I feel a bit stupid but all the problem was is that i missed out an equals sign about half way through which was causing a syntax error! Sorry for wasting your time guys! :(

Comment: @ZacEvans PLEASE tell me you're addressing the security problem, too?

Comment: It's a school project and won't actually be going to a proper company! Don't panic! :)

Answer (score 2):

To save space and time, I'm only going to show you a shortened version of how to fix this. The technique shown here will not only fix your sql formatting issue, but also fix the huge gaping security issue with the current code:

```vb
SQLcommand.CommandText = "UPDATE Pupil 
            SET Pupil_Name = @PupilName,
                Pupil_Middle_Name = @PupilMiddleName, 
                Pupil_Surname = @PupilSurName, 
                Pupil_Prefferend_Name = @PupilPreferredName, 
                Gender = @Gender , 
                DOB = @DOB,
                ...
            WHERE Pupil_ID = @PupilID"

'Guessing at parameter types/lengths here. Use actual types and lengths from your DB
SQLcommand.Parameters.Add("@PupilName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 30).Value = PDV_First_Name.Text 
SQlcommand.Parameters.Add("@PupilMiddleName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 30).Value= PDV_Middle_Name.Text
SQLcommand.Parameters.Add("@PupilSurName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 40).Value = PDV_Surname.Text
SQLcommand.Parameters.Add("@PupilPreferredName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 30).Value =  PDV_P_Name.Text
SQLcommand.Parameters.Add("@Gender", SqlDbType.Char, 1).Value = gender
SQLcommand.Parameters.Add("@DOB", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Parse(Microsoft.VisualBasic.Left(PDV_bday.Value,10))
'...
SQLcommand.Parameters.Add("@PupilID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Pupil
```